# getting red underlined error for pathParam() method in RestAssured get request & how to solve this

Tags: rest-assured, web-api-testing

need help for the below issue in RestAssured.
Why am I getting error underlined in red for pathParam() method & how to solve this

```
import static io.restassured.RestAssured.given;
import static io.restassured.RestAssured.*;

public class TC005_GetRequest {
    
    
    @Test 
    public void getReaponse() {
        Response response = given()
                            .pathParam("R1", "albums")
                            .when()
                            .get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/{R1}")
                            .then()
                                .log().all();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because there is a mismatch type.

- `.then().log().all()` --> return instance of `ValidatableResponse`
- What you want is `Response response`

To fix that:

`.then().log().all();` -> `.then().log().all().extract().response();`